# How to keep a user control from overflowing or not fitting a gridview with row definition and column definition UWP

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a grid with column definitions and row definitions. I added a user control that is bigger than the squares it should measure. I am trying to set a grid of 5x5 with 25 user controls and have them not overflow and be able to adapt to different desktop or laptop sizes without looking weird.
The squares should be same size, same height....

```
    <Grid Margin="104,0,0,76" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="940" Height="864" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition  />
            <ColumnDefinition  />
            <ColumnDefinition  />
            <ColumnDefinition  />
            <ColumnDefinition  />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition  />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <local:ucteclarapida Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"  ></local:ucteclarapida>
        <local:ucteclarapida Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"  >        </local:ucteclarapida>
    </Grid>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your Grid with **Viewbox** and set desired **Width** and **Height** of the Grid.

```
    <Viewbox VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <Grid Width="940" Height="864">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <local:ucteclarapida Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
            <local:ucteclarapida Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
        </Grid>
    </Viewbox>
```

Comment: And do I have to add a viewbox for each of the user controls which are overflowing the grid internally?

Comment: If all controls are the same size, the size is fix and you know the size then set the width and height of the grid. Eg.: user control's dimension is 100x80 then grid's width is 5*100=500 and height is 5*80=400.
If the sizes of all controls differ then you can wrap the control with viewbox and set desired width and height of the viewbox.

Comment: @Geafer, I think the issue is what if the user decides to resize the application window (the parent window). The question is, how can we make sure the user control's size follows the size of the parent application?